# Ruby versions differ in Terminal & bash

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, terminal, rvm

In Terminal, `ruby -v` gives me:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

But if I type `/bin/bash` then `ruby -v` I get:

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
```

I suspect this is something to do with my PATH config(s). My $PATH variable is different in both the above environments. There are other issues e.g. `rvm` won't run unless I go into bash mode.

For info, my `~/.bashrc` contains:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

Comment: "I don't even understand the difference between bash and vanilla Terminal". It would be really good for you to figure that out, otherwise working at the command-line is going to be really confusing for you.

Comment: OK - I'm working on that one. Presumably the different versions of Ruby points to some configuration problem that I need to fix, however?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not due to a $PATH problem. What I've learned is that RVM cannot be run unless you change your default login shell to either **Bash** or **ZSH**. Just firing up Terminal in Mac won't work. You make the global change to using Bash like this:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

(swap `/bin/bash` for whatever your bash path is, find out using `which bash`).

The RVM website does say that bash>=3.2.25 is a [prerequisite](https://rvm.io/rvm/prerequisites/), but doesn't say what that is or how to check whether you have it. It also advises you to run `rvm requirements` to check what you need - and you can't run this unless you change your shell (all quite confusing for somebody new to this).

Thanks to the replies above for getting me there in the end.

See also: [Bad: modifier error when installing RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807609/bad-modifier-error-when-installing-rvm)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like "login shell" is not enabled, you need to enable it in Terminal Emulator Preferences, sometimes it is needed to use `/bin/bash --login`.

There are also known issues with ZSH, but it seams to be unrelated.

Comment: My Terminal prefs say 'Shells open with: Default login shell (/usr/bin/login)' - I should set to Command: '/bin/bash --login'?

Comment: yes, `login` is just a link to `bash`(most likely), and does not really mean it will use a `--login` flag for shell, this is very confusing stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Try `which ruby` from "terminal" and "/bin/bash". Your 1.9.3 is inside your `~/.rvm` path.

Type `rvm info`. You should get a list of the settings for RVM.

In your `~/.bashrc` OR `~/.bash_profile`, you should have RVM's initialization code. If you don't you didn't install RVM completely and need to finish. Read all the instructions on the [RVM installation page](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/).

Comment: Thanks. Bash: '/Users/alastair/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby'. Terminal: '/usr/bin/ruby'. rvm only outputs when on bash. ~/.bashrc posted above for reference.