# Bad: modifier error when installing RVM

Tags: terminal, rvm

I'm trying to run `source /Users/alastair/.rvm/scripts/rvm`, but keep getting:

`Bad : modifier in $ (").`

Where would the problem be? Happy to paste other files in if these would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you in any case running a shell that is not **Bash** or **ZSH**? `Bash >= 3.2.25` or `ZSH >= 4.3.10` is required.

Your problem looks like you were using minimalistic shell `sh` which is not supported by **RVM**.

You can check user shell in `/etc/passwd` and change it with `chsh -s /path/to/new/shell` - list of allowed shells is available in `/etc/shells` - but make sure to pick Bash/ZSH, also note that links like sh->bash will not work as bash changes behavior based on the name that was invoked.

Comment: Yes - I'm just typing straight into terminal. If I switch to Bash it works fine, BUT will this affect anything else on my system? Am I correct in saying that Bash is just a different kind of shell through which to access the same core files?

Comment: RVM 1.x is a shell scripting code loaded directly into the shell, you could still use it in other shells only via PATH - which makes `rvm use` useless.